# WAR Dependencies in SBT

Tags: scala, gwt, sbt, war

In the following project:

https://github.com/darkfrog26/outrnet/blob/master/project/OUTRNetBuild.scala#L49

I have the "communicator-client" that contains GWT code and it currently produces a WAR artifact. I would like to be able reference that artifact in an external project but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to bring in the resources.

I'm currently attempting to use this: "com.outr.net" %% "outrnet-communicator-client" % outrNetVersion artifacts Artifact("outrnet-communicator-client", "war", "war")

Though the code compiles and builds the resources are not found in the generated WAR file when I run the code. I would be fine with modifying my project to pull the generated resources into my "communicator-server" if that would be easier but I'm not sure exactly how to accomplish that either.

Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What resources? Where are they in the project? It isn't obvious to me from looking at the project definition or source tree.

Comment: Thanks for the response Seth. I finally figured out my problem by updating my GWT project to create a JAR instead of a WAR so everything works now.